# How to plot 4D points on a 2D plane with the third coordinate being the size of the symbol and the fourth defining the color of the symbol?

Tags: plotting, charts

I have 6 sets of 4D points. Here is an example of one set :

```
{{30., 5., 111.925, 113.569}, {30., 7.5, 114.7, 158.286}, {30., 10., 115.625, 206.023},
 {30., 12.5, 115.625, 257.528}, {30., 15., 117.475, 294.663}, {30., 17.5, 119.325, 328.03},
 {30., 20., 121.175, 357.982}, {30., 22.5, 122.1, 393.646}, {30., 25., 122.1, 437.384},
 {30., 27.5, 122.1, 481.123}}
```

I want to plot the x,y coordinates of the points on the 2D plane and use the z coordinate to define the size of the symbol (bubble radius or area) and the last coordinate to define a color for that bubble. So the color will be different depending on the fourth coordinate. Any help would be appreciated !

I would like to have a 4D graphic like that :
[image: Bubble chart 4D]

Comment: ...so the third component is a radius of the circle centered at the point made from the first two components? As for the fourth, you didn't specify how one should convert the fourth component to a color.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I was not enough specific ! For the color, the max fourth coordinate of all the points must correspond to the max of the chosen color scale (red by example) and the min coordinate to the minimum of the color scale (blue by example).

Comment: Can you give an example set of points?

Comment: {{30., 5., 111.925, 113.569}, {30., 7.5, 114.7, 158.286}, {30., 10., 
  115.625, 206.023}, {30., 12.5, 115.625, 257.528}, {30., 15., 
  117.475, 294.663}, {30., 17.5, 119.325, 328.03}, {30., 20., 121.175,
   357.982}, {30., 22.5, 122.1, 393.646}, {30., 25., 122.1, 
  437.384}, {30., 27.5, 122.1, 481.123}}

Comment: Next time, just edit your question to include such additional data.

Comment: Can you add two more data set (or maybe all it is not too long)?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart) with style wrappers?:

```
BubbleChart[
    Replace[
        {{3,4,3,5},{4,1,4,8}},
        {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> Style[{a, b, c}, Lighter[Green, d/10]],
        {1}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, it really helps ! I can almost get what I expect using the Blend function instead of Lighter but I would prefer to use one of the gradient color of the classical "schemes" if possible, as Rainbow, or TemperatureMap, because next I would like to add a colored bar legend to my graph.

Answer (score 2):

Just join all your data and use J.M's code.

```
data = {{30., 5., 111.925, 113.569}, {30., 7.5, 114.7, 158.286}, {30.,
     10., 115.625, 206.023}, {30., 12.5, 115.625, 257.528}, {30., 15.,
     117.475, 294.663}, {30., 17.5, 119.325, 328.03}, {30., 20., 
    121.175, 357.982}, {30., 22.5, 122.1, 393.646}, {30., 25., 122.1, 
    437.384}, {30., 27.5, 122.1, 481.123}};

data2 = Join[{data}, {data}, {data}];

data2[[2, All, 1]] += 30;
data2[[2, All, 2]] += 10;
data2[[2, All, 3]] += 15;
data2[[2, All, 4]] += 100;

data2[[3, All, 1]] += 60;
data2[[3, All, 2]] += 15;
data2[[3, All, 3]] += 25;
data2[[3, All, 4]] += 500;

data2 = Join @@ data2;



sc = {"ThermometerColors", MinMax[data2[[All, -1]]]};
cf = ColorData[sc];

Legended[Graphics[{cf[#4], Disk[{#, #2}, #3/30]} & @@@ data2, 
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted]], BarLegend[sc]]
```

[image]

**Edit** Here is a workaround. I am not sure this is what you want. You can use `Ellipse` instead of `Disk` and scale radius differently to overcome distortion.

```
p1 = ListPlot[{{-1, -1}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 50}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/3, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted]];
p2 = Graphics[{cf[#4], Ellipsoid[{#, #2}, {#3/30, #3/20}]} & @@@ 
    data2];
Legended[Show[{p1, p2}], BarLegend[sc]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I dit and it works pretty well actually, thanks to JM and you. Just a detail (I am perfectionist...). Using this way you cannot use the option AspectRatio because it deforms the disks. As I said it is juste a detail but in the case where I use all my results the graphics is not looking good to be presented in a poster/publication.

Comment: I tried something, see my edit. Be careful, in my first post, in `Disk[center, radius] ` radius scaled by 1/30. It is up to you change or remove that scaling factor.

Answer (score 1):

Using the given data:

```
data = {{30., 5., 111.925, 113.569}, {30., 7.5, 114.7, 158.286},
        {30., 10., 115.625, 206.023}, {30., 12.5, 115.625, 257.528},
        {30., 15., 117.475, 294.663}, {30., 17.5, 119.325, 328.03},
        {30., 20., 121.175, 357.982}, {30., 22.5, 122.1, 393.646},
        {30., 25., 122.1, 437.384}, {30., 27.5, 122.1, 481.123}};

sc = {"ThermometerColors", MinMax[data[[All, -1]]]}; cf = ColorData[sc];

Legended[Graphics[{cf[#4], Disk[{#, #2}, #3/100]} & @@@ data, Frame -> True],
         BarLegend[sc]]
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: Thanks it works but it looks weird when I import all my data and not just one sample : 6 columns of "bubbles" like the one you plotted (that's ok) but a very small graphics in comparison with the bar legend. I edit my question to add this info.